# contact form 7 mail not sending

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, contact-form-7

I have used contact form 7 for one of my wordpress sites.
I have also integrated wp-mail-smtp for sending mail.
In local site is running properly but When I configure it on server it gives error.
Problem is though I get success message but it does not send mail to specified email id.
and when I try to send the test message from smtp, it gives below error

```
The SMTP debugging output is shown below:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Can any one specify the problem?

Comment: I think the best person to answer or help on this your server support person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMTP needs to be authenticated. Download and install the WP Mail SMTP plugin. Once the local server information is added in Settings >> Email, the emails should get sent out to any outside email addresses.

Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Please try with "host as localhost"

Just try hope will helps

Comment: that brings up the exakt same error.
the problem is with the hosting company e.g. they use a firewall. you should ask them for help.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to wipe this from the "from" field to get my emails to get through:

[your-name] <[your-email]>

Just left it blank and it worked.

Comment: I could kiss you right now. For others dealing with this, Contact Form 7 will still throw a syntax error if you leave it blank, but just save it as is and it will  work assuming you have WP Mail SMTP configured properly.

Comment: seriously, you're the Hero! I left it blank and it works though the form indicates error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing a plugin for SMTP (smtp-wp, WP Mail SMTP, etc.) Make sure that configuration in the Contact Form 7 configuration, the text area "Message Body" contains at least the code `[your-message]`.