# Contact form 7 NOT working on my WAMP localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp, contact-form-7

So, i knew that when using CF7 on localhost was unable to send email to your mail box. It wasn't the first time i'm using CF7, so i know that you still can test out the form and it will able to show up a successful green border message and said that your message was successful sent.

But now the problem is i'm not only cannot test my form and it keep show up the red border message said that [There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.] So how can i fix it?

I also did some research about this problems and it's about  [mail server was down, inaccessible or experiencing other problems / contact your host for support / contact your server admin. ] I did installed the smpt plugin before i test  the form (because i've found  a solution said that you can send your email through your localhost by installing smpt plugin, so i decided to give it a try)   and it turn out not working so i thought that it was the smpt plugin affected the CF7 not working, and i go ahead and uninstall smpt plugin but my CF7 form still not working. I've also tried uninstall and reinstall CF7 but my CF7 form still not working.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

This is the form

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Subject<br />
    [text your-subject] </p>

<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

This is the mail setting
[image]

Comment: Check for your e-mail-function in your localhost. This causes many problems.

Comment: Check this out: [contact form 7 mail not sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276560/contact-form-7-mail-not-sending?rq=1)

Comment: @SacrumDeus May I know which e-mail-function file should I check? I mean the name of the file.

Comment: @SacrumDeus The form keep loading like about 3 mins and nothing happen

Comment: check the link out. There are many, which have the same problem with localhost.

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed? Windows does not by default!!! Or does WP use something like phpMailer?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't have anything else installed. Before that I also DIDN'T install anything plugin as well and I can test my CF7 form and everything works fine and perfectly. Now I just want it to show the green border and successful message. Do you know what is the problems I was having now?

Answer (score 2):

Install **[hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/)** on your server. Or install smtp plugin then add smtp details of your email.