# Contact form 7 is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, email

The contact form gives

> *There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.*

and cpanel gives

> *Attention! Please register your email IDs used
>   in non-smtp mails through cpanel plugin. Unregistered email IDs will
>   not be allowed in non-smtp emails sent through scripts. Go to Mail
>   section and find "Registered Mail IDs" plugin in paper_lantern theme.*

how to solve this?

Comment: Isn't this pretty clear? You are being asked to register your email id from which the mail is being sent

Comment: i have registered with the email in cpanel but still the issue is coming

Answer (score 0):

Several things you can do to fix the issue.

1. From email should be abc@yourdomain.com. For example if your domain is abc.com and you want info@abc.com, then in the form field, you should put info@abc.com in "Form" section
2. For me, in the cPanel, making the email addresses registered fixed the issue.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277862/2724286 
   The SMTP needs to be authenticated. Download and install the WP Mail SMTP plugin. Once the local server information is added in Settings >> Email, the emails should get sent out to any outside email addresses.

Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/